Cannot create shared library(singleton service) with "Angular-Architects Micro-Front-End Federation Module" with Multiple-Repository Architecture
Cannot create shared library(singleton service) with "Angular-Architects Micro-Front-End Federation Module" with Multiple-Repository Architecture
The documentation given by Angular-Architects does not give any details on how to have a singleton library shared amongst different micro-services.  It has details FOR mono-repo architecture.  This is not the case for me.
